# EE 3 Live look button

Tags: control-panel, livelook

Can someone tell me where the Live look button is located in the v3 control panel? In v2 it was alongside the entry title in the edit listing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be there also, but there's currently a bug and it's not showing up:

Solution and info here:

https://expressionengine.com/support/bugs/23218/live-look-templates-no-longer-working